# Migrating app to AngularJS?

Tags: java, angularjs, web-applications, single-page-application

i have existing web application where most of the time pages are submitted traditional way(like document.form.submit or )
I am planning to migrate to angularJS which i am [learning](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/angularjs/angularjs_views.htm). **I am not sure how we can submit form in traditional way (without ajax) with angularJS ?**
I know it won't be true Single Page App(SPA), but for starting i would like to go this way.

**Approach for migrating traditional app to SPA :-**
In future , i would like to go for SPA in which i will submitting the form thru ajax way using AngularJS. I have vague understanding
how will i approach this but would like to get experts advice on this.

**My Understanding:-**
Say i land to welcome page with a link for customer creation. I will make the ajax call from WelcomeController(angularJS Controller) to my servlet/spring controller
which will return html response containing js file. HTML response will be conatining below

1)HTML will be containing ng-view and ng-template which will be used by routeProvide

2)One of the js files will be containing routeProvider Info to map the ng-template with view

Please correct me if this is right approach ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was exactly looking for [Single Page App with AngularJS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rahul4_saxena/single-page-application-spa-using-angularjs-web-api-and-m/) which describes how you can have full fledged SPA web app using AngularJS(with features like router,controller,service etc) in a clear and succinct way

Answer (score 1):

Use AngularJS for data-binding and form-validation.  When you want to submit a form, you can rely on jQuery:

```
<div ng-controller="ctrl">
     <form id="myform" name="myform">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="person.name" name="person.name" /> <br />
        <button ng-click="submit(person)">Submit</button>
     </form>
</div>
```

Script

```
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
     $scope.submit = function(person) {
         if ($scope.myform.$valid) {
             $('#myform').submit();
         }
     }
});
```

For this to work, make sure you give your input fields properly scoped names so that it binds to your MVC models.

This approach does have its limitations. For example, input fields that use ngModel should not have any $formatters/$parsers which limits you to simple formats.

Comment: Thanks pixelbits. I was wondering if angularJS also provides this(otherwise jquery is always there as you said).

Comment: No, AngularJS does not support traditional non-ajax requests.

Comment: Thanks pixelbits. Regarding approach, is there any good alternative  or what can be other approach?

Comment: If you plan on embracing ajax, then using Angular's $http service is the way to go.

Comment: Yes i agree on ajax. But my main confusion how to include the html response (of different jsp page) in single page ? for example :- right now i submit the form in traditional way and navigated to page required. But i am trying to get the right way how ajax response(instead response from traditional submission) of various user events will be included ?

Comment: Not sure I can give you advice on that, because I would not recommend doing that. And partially because I don't think its possible.

Comment: As you said "you won't recommend that".  May be you are true. But i am not getting how single page application is possible without this ? So i am just trying to  evaluate the options. Can you point me to some example how  can i make the application a tru SPA/totally ajax based. May be i am sounding weird here but all tutorial are very basic. So need your advice guys